# How to replace every invalid character in a string with a different one in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace invalid characters in a string by a '_'
I tried using preg_replace like this

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', '_', $value);
```

but if my string was 'value1234' it's converted to 'value_'
What I need is every single invalid character to be replaced by a '*' which would return 'value*___'
I need to apply this with a complex regex so I want to avoid looping and testing each character if possible.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Then remove `+`, use `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '_', $value);`. What complex regex do you mean?

Comment: It was definetly time for a coffee break... Thanks for pointing at the issue. Please add this as an answer so I can confirm your answer. Thanks